# How to include small functions when profiling via instrumentation in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

Older versions of Visual Studio had an ability to turn *off* the exclusion of small functions from instrumentation for performance profiling.

Frustratingly, I can't find the option in Visual Studio 2019, even though in the Output pane I see the message:

> Info VSP3049: Small functions will be excluded from instrumentation.

How can I disable this option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get it by clicking the gear icon next to the Instrumentation option:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]